# Chromium giving me "bus error (core dumped)" after recovering from corrupted filesystem using fsck

Tags: chromium, fsck, busybox

So all was well a little while ago. I've been running into a series of problems and every solution leads to another problem. This is the series of events that led to the current state of my computer

1. I wanted to upgrade all my pip packages, so I ran

   ```
   sudo pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 sudo pip install -U
   ```

   that I found from StackOverflow.
2. This was running while I continued to use Chromium and edit in Sublime Text. During this, suddenly the command running in my terminal started to print out plenty of IOErrors and Sublime wouldn't save files, saying my file system is read only. I tried rebooting my PC.
3. My computer didn't boot up properly. It showed a terminal with an error message and an `(Initramfs)` prompt. I don't remember the exact error message, but it said something about filesystem error on `/dev/sda2`, and something about an orphaned linked list.
4. I ran `fsck -y /dev/sda2`, then tried rebooting again. This time, it booted up. However, now Chromium crashes immediately after opening. When I run it from the terminal, I get an error `bus error (core dumped)`

Any insight on what happened and why, and guidance on troubleshooting/fixing this are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it by running

```
rm ~/.cache/chromium
rm ~/.config/chromium
```

and then restarting chromium